# Have make fail if unit tests fail

Tags: makefile, return-value, gnu-make

I have a makefile for compiling a static library. This makefile has a rule for compiling a unit test suite associated with the static library. Once the test suite is compiled, a python script is invoked to run the tests and log the results. It looks like this:

```
unit:
    $(MAKE) -C cXbase/unit
    python $(TESTS_RUNNER) $(UNIT_TESTS_EXEC) $(UNIT_TESTS_LOG)
```

I use Python to make the tests invocation portable. Right now, everything works fine: the tests compile and the test runner is called and logs everything properly in Linux and Windows. Only, when a test fail, I would like to stop the whole make process and return an error. More precisely, I would like not to be able to `make all` or to `make unit` when a unit test fails (or many).

If a unit test fails, the Python script returns a specific exit code. I would like to be able to **capture it in a portable way** and have make fail if that exit code is captured.

Would you have any recommendations on how to do this? I have found nothing convincing or portable elsewhere.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a *return value* or an *exit code*?

Comment: Make will abort if a command in a recipe gives a non-zero exit status. If that isn't good enough, we must capture the exit status *within the command*, and the question is **"how portable is portable enough?"** I know how to capture and test it in bash; are you interested in other shells?

Comment: @Beta I would like it to work in bash and cmd (Windows)

Comment: And what do you want in case the exit status is something other than the special value?

Comment: @Beta Then `make` can go on as usual, all tests have passed.

Comment: Use Cygwin instead of cmd, see http://cygwin.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the solution was way simpler than I imagined. The python exit code reflects directly in `make` it's exit code. In other words, if the script fails (exit code other than 0), `make` sees this as a command error and stops.

I had an error in my Python script exit code handling upon tests failure which hid this from me. Now it is solved and it works perfectly.

I found out about this here: [Handling exit code returned by python in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259660/handling-exit-code-returned-by-python-in-shell-script)