# How to have make fail on some warnings but not others

Tags: makefile, error-handling

I have a make file that includes:

```
%.dat: %.txt
   ... PREPROCESSING OF TEXT FILE
   tidy -o $*.html $<
   ... FURTHER PROCESSING
```

`tidy` produces lots of warnings that I can suppress with the flag `--show-warnings false`, but despite supressing the warnings, the exit status from `tidy` still 1 instead of 0, and so `make` fails part way through the recipe. How can I have `make` continue in the face of `tidy` giving exit status 1 while still allowing `make` to fail if any other recipe gives warnings?

I have looked at these two question ([Have make fail if unit tests fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957679/have-make-fail-if-unit-tests-fail) and [gcc, make: how to disable fail on warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414242/gcc-make-how-to-disable-fail-on-warning)) but neither seems to deal with this problem.

AFTER EDIT: In [Make: how to continue after a command fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670130/make-how-to-continue-after-a-command-fails), the question relates to how one gets `make` to continue after *any* non-zero exit status in executing a particular command, whereas in my case, I want an exit status of 2 from `tidy` indicating errors, to cause `make` to fail, but I want an exit status of 1 from `tidy`, indicating warnings`to allow`make to continue`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make: how to continue after a command fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670130/make-how-to-continue-after-a-command-fails)

Comment: I've edited the question to distinguish it from the suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest solution:

```
tidy -o $*.html $< || true
```

So if tidy's exit code isn't zero the `true` produces zero exit code.

But check the tidy's [exit codes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tidy):

> Exit Status
>
> 0
>
> All input files were processed successfully.
>
> 1
>
> There were warnings.
>
> 2
>
> There were errors.

Maybe you want skip only the error code `1`. In this case:

```
tidy -o $*.html $< || [ $$? -eq 1 ] && true
```

Comment: Nice. The general lesson I take from this (I hope correctly) is to devise a shell command, incorporating the critical recipe parts, sot that the shell command produces the correct error code structure.